# How to create home screen or lock screen widget using jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I want to implement home screen or lock screen widgets using jetpack compose.

I do some R&D but I didn't find any document related to this topic.

So help me.

Thank you in advanced

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jetpack Compose Glance to create app widgets is in alpha but you can access it by adding this dependency to your project:

```
implementation "androidx.glance:glance-appwidget:1.0.0-alpha05"
```

You then need to extend your class to `GlanceAppWidgets`. Here is a code snippet from the doc:

```
class GreetingsWidget(private val name: String): GlanceAppWidget() {
    @Composable
    override fun Content() {
        Text(text = "Hello $name")
    }
}

class GreetingsWidgetReceiver : GlanceAppWidgetReceiver() {

    override val glanceAppWidget = GreetingsWidget("Glance")
}
```

Please have a look [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2021/12/announcing-jetpack-glance-alpha-for-app.html) for the documentation.